# Disable submit button after a reCaptchaV2 timeout

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, recaptcha, commandbutton

How to disable a submit button after a reCaptcha V2 timeout?

Like I need the button to be disabled when this message is visible on reCaptcha widget.

**`Verification expired. Check the checkbox again.`**

I'm disabling and re-enabling the submit button based on reCaptcha response as of now but couldn't figure out a way to link it with timeout. Any leads preferably using JS would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `expired-callback` attribute and callback or configure this callback in the Recaptcha configuration.

Answering in kind. If you need help with code, please provide some examples and I'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still needing this answer, I had success with expired-callback. Submit button is initially disabled, then is enabled on reCaptcha check box, then disabled again on reCaptcha timeout. This is all in the same html page containing the form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6L_my_site_key" id="captcha" data-callback="enableBtn" data-expired-callback="recaptchaExp">
  
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn" name="submit" disabled="disabled"></div>
         
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function enableBtn(){
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").disabled = false;
  } 
  function recaptchaExp(){
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

This does not offer any reCaptcha validation, just basic prevention of submission. I have AJAX / PHP validate the reCaptcha on the server-side.